# xcode 4 symbol navigator and 'jump to definition'

Tags: xcode4

hopefully a nice, simple Xcode 4 question...
In the symbol editor, I can see all my methods for my classes. If I click on a Method, I get shown the class definition in my '.h' file . How do I get it to simply take me to the implementation of the method (in the .cpp file)?

I know that from the definition of my class I can click on the method and use 'jump to definition' however, if I got there by selecting the method from the symbol navigator, the whole line is selected and the 'jump to definition' option is not available. (meaning I need to re-select only the method name, and then do jump to definition which seems long-winded)

I can also option-click and get the assistant editor - but it just shows the same view in another panel (i.e. the 'h' file)

I'm sure i'm missing something obvious so please help me out...

Answer (score 0):

CMD-CLICK on your symbol name to jump to it in code (works for OS symbols, too.)

For OS symbols, OPTION-click to bring up little documentation window.  Use the docs-icon to get the full docs.